# Bootstrap dropdown issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Getting a bug using the dropdown, if I call it from the console using `$('.profile-dropdown').dropdown('toggle');` it pop up but from the script fails

```
<ul class="profile-dropdown dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  <li>Profile Page</li>
  <li>Settings</li>
  <li>Logout</li>
</ul>

....

<img src="{{ request.user.profile.first.profile_icon }}" class="profile-icon img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail">
```

jquery

```
$('.profile-icon').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.profile-dropdown').dropdown('toggle');
    console.log('a');
});
```

but logs `a` to the console.

Comment: Show also the html

Comment: Make sure to include jquery before the bootstrap js